# Is a Windows license valid on a "computer of Theseus"?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, software, oregon

If I buy a computer with a Windows license, and then replace every part of the computer one at a time (cloning the old hard drive to the new one then erasing the old one, or reinstalling Windows on my new drive using the allowed backup copy), is my Windows license legally valid on the "computer of Theseus"? (I'm specifically asking about the license contract; whether or not Windows will detect a valid digital license is irrelevant.) If not, at what point during the replacements is the license invalidated?

Comment: The practical observation is that Microsoft has nothing to gain here. The set of people to which this applies is small, but they are technically skilled and Microsoft benefits from good relations with them. The law does not matter when there is no conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the terms of the license for your copy of Windows. With a retail license, you can replace as many parts on the computer as you want or just install it on a completely new computer without changing the computer piecemeal. Under [that license](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/UseTerms/Retail/Windows/11/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_11_English.htm), the software can be used on the "licensed device", and

> “device” means a local hardware system (whether physical or virtual)
> with an internal storage device capable of running the software. A
> hardware partition or blade is considered to be a device.For purposes
> of this agreement, “device” does not include any hardware system
> (whether physical or virtual) on which the software is installed or
> accessed solely for remote use over a network

See also §4 on transfer, where is says "you may transfer the software to another device that belongs to you". For OEM licenses, you'd have to read your device-specific license (if you can find it), which are probably tied to the motherboard.